# How To Split a String by comma and assign it to variables in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

how to split the string shown below and assign it to 4 different variables like name, price, image, and quantity

[image]

Comment: Please mention [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), add code that you have tried or the state of your code where the relevant data is present.

Comment: String [ ] str = stringToSplit.split( " , " );  // will  split on comma and store it into an array;

Answer (score 1):

String [ ] str = Any_String.split(" , ")

// Whatever u will give inside those brrackets , string will be splitted based on that. In this case the splitter is ,

str will be a list , and u can get its values using its index[ ]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late to the game, but what you want to do can be done.  However, probably not as cleanly as you would hope.  You can, as previously stated, split your string into an array **and then** create variables using that array as follows (I added code to remove the curly braces too).

```
final list = str.replaceFirst('}', '', str.length - 1).replaceFirst('{', '').split(',');
final String name = list[0], price = list[1], image = list[2], quantity = list[3];
```

Of course, this assumes that each string entry contains four items.  If it contains fewer than four, you will receive a `RangeError` exception.